# Using Foolproof RequiredIf with an Enum

Tags: c#, enums, data-annotations, foolproof-validation

We are trying to use the Foolproof validation annotation `[RequiredIf]` to check if an email address is needed. We also created an enum to avoid using a lookup table id in the ViewModel. The code looks like this:

```
public enum NotificationMethods {
        Email = 1,
        Fax = 2
}
```

Then in the ViewModel:

```
[RequiredIf("NotificationMethodID", NotificationMethods.Email)]
public string email {get; set;}
```

In this senario we do not get an error when email is unfilled but selected as the notification type. Conversely this works as expected:

```
[RequiredIf("NotificationMethodID", 1)]
public string email {get; set;}
```

The only other reference to this I have found is here: https://foolproof.codeplex.com/workitem/17245

Comment: Can you show us what that `"NotificationMethodID"` property looks like?

Comment: It is an int - `public int NotificationMethodID {get; set;}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that your method `NotificationMethodID` is returning an `int`, the reason your check is failing is that, in c#, each [`enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) is its own type, inheriting from [`System.Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  I.e. if you do

```
var value = NotificationMethods.Email;
string s = value.GetType().Name;
```

You will see `s` has the value `"NotificationMethods"` not `"Int32"`.

If you try to check the equality of an int with an enum directly, you get a compiler error:

```
var same = (1 == NotificationMethods.Email); // Gives the compiler error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'NotificationMethods'"
```

If you [box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the enum and int values first (which is what happens when they are passed to the constructor of [`RequiredIfAttribute`](https://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Foolproof/RequiredIf.cs)) then there is no compiler error but `Equals()` returns false, since the types differ:

```
var same = ((object)1).Equals((object)NotificationMethods.Email);
Debug.WriteLine(same) // Prints "False".
```

To check equality of underlying integer values, you can explicitly cast `NotificationMethods.Email` to an integer before boxing:

```
var same = ((object)1).Equals((object)((int)NotificationMethods.Email));
Debug.WriteLine(same); // Prints "True"
```

And in the attribute application:

```
[RequiredIf("NotificationMethodID", (int)NotificationMethods.Email)]
public string email {get; set;}
```

You might also consider using `const int` values instead of enums:

```
public static class NotificationMethods
{
    public const int Email = 1;
    public const int Fax = 2;
}
```

Comment: I got as far into your answer as "Given that your method NotificationMethodID is returning an int" before I realized my very rookie mistake, thank you. I should have caught it on your comment.