# MVC Foolproof - RequiredIf - Greater Than - ENum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums, foolproof-validation

I am trying to use the MVC Foolproof Validation toolkit to enforce a field has a value if a earlier status field has reached a certain value...

The Status field type is an ENum with defined `int` values.

```
public enum RequestStatusENum { New = 10, 
                                Processing = 20,
                                Rejected = 30,
                                Withdrawn = 40,
                                Confirmed = 50,
                                Cancelling = 60,
                                Cancelled = 70 }
```

Once the status has reached `Confirmed`, I need to ensure that the `ConfirmationNumber` field has a value

```
public RequestStatusENum Status { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Confirmation Number")]
[RequiredIf("Status", Operator.EqualTo,
    RequestStatusENum.Confirmed, ErrorMessage = "Confirmation Number required")]
public string ConfirmationNumber { get; set; }
```

With the above setting, it works fine and validates that the field has data, however, if I change to the following, no validation occurs.

```
[RequiredIf("Status", Operator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    RequestStatusENum.Confirmed, ErrorMessage = "Confirmation Number required")]
```

or this

```
[RequiredIf("Status", Operator.GreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    (int)RequestStatusENum.Confirmed, ErrorMessage = "Confirmation Number required")]
```

I've looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283689/using-foolproof-requiredif-with-an-enum) and whilst it is similar, it's not as that is an explicit `EqualsTo` comparison, not a `GreaterThanOrEqualTo`